# Java program to query database error

Tags: java, sql

I'm making a program that uses Java as a front to do some SQL manipulations of data. I've got most of it set up, and I am able to make the connection to my database, however for some reason when I try and run my query, it returns a line saying "Could not execute query" and I cannot figure out why it can't execute the query.

```
public class application {

   public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception,
                 IOException, SQLException {
      try {
          Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println ("Could not load the driver");
      }
      String user = readEntry("Enter userid: ");
      String pass = readEntry("Enter password: ");
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (
                  "jdbc:oracle:thin:@serveraddress",user,pass);

      boolean done = false;
      do {
         printMenu();
         System.out.print("Type in your option: ");
         System.out.flush();
         String ch = readLine();
         System.out.println();
         switch (ch.charAt(0)) {
             case '1': studentModules(conn);
                 break;
             //some other cases
             case '0': done = true;
                 break;
             default : System.out.println(" Not a valid option ");
         } //switch
     } while(!done);

  } // main

  private static void studentModules(Connection conn) throws SQLException, IOException {

  String sqlString = null;
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

  sqlString = "select Student_id" +
            "from STUDENT;";

  ResultSet rset;
  ResultSet rset2;

  try {
     rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlString);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
     System.out.println("Could not execute query");
     stmt.close();
     return;
  }

  String print;

  while (rset.next()) {

      print = rset.getString(1) + ": ";

      sqlString = "select Module_code" +
              "from EXAM" +
              "where Student_id = " + rset.getString(1) + ";";

      try {
         rset2 = stmt.executeQuery(sqlString);
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println("Could not execute query");
         stmt.close();
         return;
      }

      while (rset2.next()) {
         print = print + rset.getString(1) + " ";
      }

      System.out.println(print);

   }

   stmt.close();

}
```

I know it's a long piece of code, but I cannot figure why it goes wrong. I know it is erroring and being caught when trying to query "SELECT Student_id FROM STUDENT", but that query isn't wrong and I can't understand why it would throw an error there?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you catch `SQLException` you should print it's stacktrace somewhere and there should be be more information about what is wrong.

Comment: you need a space between `Student_id` and `from` in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"select Student_id" +
        "from STUDENT;";
```

resolves to something like `select Student_idfrom STUDENT` which will not compute. Do

```
"select Student_id from STUDENT";
```

instead.

```
sqlString = "select Module_code" +
          "from EXAM" +
          "where Student_id = " + rset.getString(1) + ";";
```

should be

```
sqlString = "select Module_code from EXAM " +
          " where Student_id = " + rset.getString(1);
```

likewise.

Don't code the final ';' by the way - some databases (like ORACLE) hate that a lot.

Oh and your loop-variable in final resultSet you need to access rset2 instead of rset here I guess:

```
while (rset2.next()) {
     print = print + rset2.getString(1) + " "; //CHECK
  }
```

**Additional**

You might want to think about using a `PreparedStatement` as well - String contatenations will open the door to SQL injection which you might want to prevent.

Comment: This is it! Icannot believe I was silly enough to forget the spaces, but I didn't know about the semi colons! I'd never have guessed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: There's others who pointed out the same thing - it would be nice to upvote their answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are invalid:

```
  sqlString = "select Student_id" +
            "from STUDENT;";
```

Evaluates to "select Student_idfrom Studen", so you are missing a blank.

Same goes for

```
  sqlString = "select Module_code" +
          "from EXAM" +
          "where Student_id = " + rset.getString(1) + ";";
```

where you are missing a blank between "Module_code" and "from" and "EXAM" and "where".

You should do something like

```
  sqlString = "select Student_id " +
            "from STUDENT;";
```

and

```
sqlString = "select Module_code " +
          "from EXAM " +
          "where Student_id = " + rset.getString(1) + ";";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"select Student_id" + "from STUDENT;";
```

won't add any space between the two strings, but you definitely need it